# OneNote and GroupWise

Tags: microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2010, groupwise

I love the integration between the Microsoft OneNote 2010 beta and Outlook, where you can press a button to send an email to a note page, and the email will be nicely formatted when it gets there, with attachments preserved, etc.

Does anyone know of any similar integration for Novell GroupWise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OneNote2010 installs a printer driver so you can "SendToOneNote" from any app that can print, although the end result will be an embedded image rather than text / layout based. Not as nice as the integration with Outlook (and other apps eg Firefox plugin) but maybe better than nothing?

Comment: Cool.  Is this the plugin you were referring to: http://www.freewebs.com/onenote/ ?